# is it possible to run Quartz Scheduler on Apache Mesos

Tags: quartz-scheduler, mesos, mesosphere

both have very complementary features and it would be great to be able to have the schedule flexibility of Quartz, with the distributed computing of Apache Mesos.
I couldn't find anything on google.
Has anybody tried this?

Comment: Not exactly an answer for your question, but take a look at https://github.com/mesos/chronos

Comment: @serejja unfortunately Chronos is not as good as Quartz for the schedule feature. Only limited options are available. Quartz allows much more things.